# Многоуровневый вывод данных из БД

Tags: php, mysql

Допустим в БД есть таблица имеющая седующие поля:

```
id, name, parent_id
```

И записано 5 строк:

```
1, value, 0
2, value, 1
3, value, 2
4, value, 3
5, value, 4
```

Все вроде ничего если знать заранее что дерево будет иметь 5 уровней.

Как составлять код запроса при условии что конечный уровень неизвестен?

З.Ы. Просьба натолкнуть на мысль, решение за меня сочинять не нужно)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут уже что-то такое было, не помню, решилось или нет. В общем, в чистом mysql <5.0 нерешаемо без php принципиально, в 5.0+ смотрим [сюда](http://club.shelek.ru/viewart.php?id=307), раздел "Классическая иерархия — id и parent_id.". Но это если у вас есть право создания хранимых процедур.

Так на php суть же просто: делаем рекурсивную функцию, например, `gettree($pid = 0)`, которая получит все корневые разделы, потом для каждого `$section->children = gettree($section->id);`. Можно соптимизировать, собрав сначала массив уровней: выбриаем первые разделы, засовываем в `$levels[0]` массивом вида ($id => $object). Потом собираем все id первого уровня и делаем запрос `"SELECT * ... WHERE pid IN(".implode(', ', $pids).")"`. Потом для 3 и т.д., пока запрос не вернет пустоту. А потом опять проходим по всем уровням и засовываем разделы в children предыдущего.

Если критериев выбора нет - тупо грузим все ("SELECT * FROM sections WHERE 1") и разбираем на php, опять же, рекурсивненько =) начиная с $section->pid==0.

Comment: Как раз на PHP, метку не для массовки ставил)

Comment: Обновил ответ.

Comment: Суть уловлена, спасибо) завтра буду ковырятся)